# jquery ui tabs change hash to external url

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs, hashtag

I need jquery ui tabs to link to external URL not hashtag like #tab1. This is code i have:

```
    <li class="ui-tabs-nav-item" id="nav-1">
    <a href="#1">Tab1</a>
    </li>
```

Need it like this:

```
    <li class="ui-tabs-nav-item" id="nav-1">
    <a href="http://www.page.com" id="1">Tab1</a>
    </li>
```

Can jquery read id (or class, title, rel...) to activate tab, instead of hash href=#1 ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

### First response

It depends on what you mean by "link to"?

If you want to "load" the external url into a tab-panel then you could use an iframe in the tab-panel. When you click on that tab it simply shows the contents of the external url in the iframe. You could use beforeActivate option to set the iframe url if you want to delay loading of the iframe until the tab is clicked. See:
http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-beforeActivate

If you want to redirect or open a new window with the external url when you click on the tab then you want to take a look at the beforeActivate and simply redirect to the url you require. E.g. window.location="http://www.page.com"

If by "external url" you mean another page on the same site then all you need to do is set the href relative to your current page. E.g. href="test-page.html" Take a look at:
Take a look at: http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#ajax

### In response to your first comment

In that case jQuery tabs is an overkill... you could just use a formatted <ul> element but if you must use tabs, try this:

Javascript:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
    active: false,
    collapsible: true,
    beforeActivate: function (event, ui) {
        window.open($(ui.newTab).find('a').attr('href'), '_blank');
        return false;
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://www.google.com/">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">Page 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the jsfiddle for it:
http://jsfiddle.net/p2GEf/1/

Comment: Tabs are working on hover. On hover it shows some content in div but on click it should open that external url (not local within same site) in new browser window (no iframe).